# SCNNode names, suggestions for a unique value?

Tags: hash

My app reads a text file line-by-line, copies the data into an array of `Card` objects, and then creates `SceneKit` nodes for each one. Some of the `Card`s modify or make iterative copies of the data on earlier lines, so there is no 1:1 correspondence between line numbers and the number of `SCNNode`s.

I'm trying to come up with a way that I can uniquely name the nodes when they are created so that I can use `childNodeWithName(_:recursively:)` to find them if. Using the `Card`s index in the array is not useful because that might change - the user might add or remove objects or reorder them, for instance.

Is there some sort of unique ID or hash on the `Card` (or any) objects themselves that I can access that I might use for this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer to your question depends on what a `Card` represents and is completely independent of SceneKit. I guess it's up to you to find a hash function that works well for what's contained in a `Card`, or you can simply store a `NSUUID` in the `Card`'s initializer.

Comment: NSUUID sounds like the solution I was looking for. Are these relatively efficient for searching?

Comment: well, if you use `childNodeWithName(_:recursively:)` the performance cost will always be the same. You are comparing strings and how you generate them (in your case `NSUUID.UUIDString`) isn't important